# Changing OS from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

So my computer has 2 operating systems on it, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. When I downloaded Ubuntu i had a ton of trouble booting windows 7 up again, then I downloaded GRUB and switched my default OS back to Windows. Sadly though, I'm trying to get into writing php with Apache. I Downloaded WAMP (windows Apache MySQL php) but for some reason, php doesn't work. I though i would try downloading LAMP (Linux apace MySQL php) but whenever I boot up my PC, I don't get a chance to enter the Ubuntu OS. How could I get back to running Ubuntu?

---

Actually, it doesn't prompt me for a boot menu or anything. It just goes straight to the windows symbol

Comment: A screenshot or explaining where the booting process is stuck would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up how to access the Boot Menu for your PC. (It varies by Manufacturer) There is usually a key sequence that interrupts the boot process and allows you to select an OS. Common keys for this are "Esc" or F2